# Юбилейный в отношении к числу

Tags: семантика

Можно ли употреблять слово "юбилейный" не по отношению к дате: юбилейная лекция, юбилейный пирожок (в значении *кратный по счёту 25)?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, но с соблюдением чувства меры и уместности иронии. Дело в том, что всерьёз о юбилее говорят в связи со *значительными* событиями. Для пирожков двадцать пять - количество незначительное, и даже в ироническом смысле на юбилей "не тянет"; можно говорить, например,  о *тысяче* пирожков, сделанных вручную и о гораздо больших количествах, произведенных промышленно, - эти количества должны производить некоторое впечатление, чтобы условно назвать соответствующий по счёту пирожок "юбилейным"; при этом контекст должен допускать некоторую иронию.

Answer (score 0):

Если уж говорить о юбилее, то число, согласно Торе, должно быть кратным 50. А поскольку в законе Моисея  50-ый, то-есть юбилейный год - год свободы и благотворительности, то юбилейный пирожок лучше подарить ближнему. И полностью согласен с Alex_ander, прежде всего - ирония, ирония и жалость, лучшее сочетание, если верить Стругацким.

Comment: «50-ый, то-есть» ======= Правильно: 50-й, то есть.